# How to close notifications when clicking on any notification box

Tags: javascript, notifications

By setting a sending an AJAX request to the server and checking the status of my database records, I read and show a notification on the browser page for the necessary records.

I have set click for the event notification to close the notification.
The problem I have is that it only works correctly for the latest click event notification and older notifications either don't react or cause the web page to open in a new tab.

What is wrong with my code? And how do I make clicking on any notification close that notification?

```
var n = null;
function notif() {
    n = new Notification('the Title', {
        body: 'the Body',
        requireInteraction: false
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
        n.close()
    }, 3000);

    n.onclick = function () {
        n.close();
    };
}

 $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "fun.php",
        success: function (response) {
                let data = response.data;
                let data_len = data.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < data_len; i++) {
                    notif();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: After "n.close();", reset the value of "n". As per your code, "**n = null;**"

Comment: You should make `n` a variable in the scope of the `notif` function.